# Ubuntu - Run command on start-up with "sudo"

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.10

I would like to run a `sudo` command when Ubuntu starts up (before anyone logs in):

```
sudo searchd
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

You can add the command in the `/etc/rc.local` script that is executed at the end of startup.

Write the command before `exit 0`. Anything written after `exit 0` will never be executed.

Comment: Before, for sure. Anything written after `exit 0` will never be executed.

Comment: Hi I also have and rvmsudo command to be executed in same situation. the command normally would ask for password. Will there be any issues if I place the command directly in /etc/rc.local ?

Comment: @fmonegaglia It depends. If you want the command to be started, and the script waits for it to finish before continuing to the next command on the script, then no `&`. If you want the following command to be started even if the current one is not finished, add a `&`.

Comment: @NoOne Check access rights on this file for the current user. Starting editor command with sudo may do the trick.

Comment: could you elaborate more? which program executes that script? seems like i don't have this file on a non-ubuntu (arch) distribution .. does ubuntu use another init system than systemd? or just some other config?

Comment: @philx_x Have a look at this post: https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd

Comment: This doesnt seem to work on 18.04. I'm starting a daemon in `rc.local`, but it isn't there after login.

Comment: @oarfish, lots of input about this on the Intenet. First check that `/etc/rc.local` does exist, that it has executable permissions and that it starts with a correct hashbang (#!/usr/bin for example).
You also may have to run `systemctl enable rc-local.service`, but it is usually already enabled, and the failure to start comes from the previous requirements that are not fulfilled.

Comment: Of course it exists and yes, I did set the executable bit. When trying to enable the service, I only get `The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units) […].` Any advice on this?

Answer (score 9):

Edit the tty configuration in `/etc/init/tty*.conf` with a shellscript as a parameter :

```
(...)
exec /sbin/getty -n -l  theInputScript.sh -8 38400 tty1
(...)
```

This is assuming that we're editing tty1 and the script that reads input is theInputScript.sh.

A word of warning this script is run as root, so when you are inputing stuff to it you have root priviliges. Also append a path to the location of the script.

Important: the script when it finishes, has to invoke the /sbin/login otherwise you wont be able to login in the terminal.

Comment: this answer was pretty useful for me when building our product appliance, thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Nice answers. You could also set Jobs (i.e., run commands) with "[Crontab](https://crontab.guru/)" for more flexibility (which provides different
options to run scripts, loggin the outputs, etc.), although it requires more time
to be understood and set properly:

- [How to run a command on startup in Ubuntu?](http://geekstuff.org/2018/06/24/how-to-run-a-command-on-startup-in-ubuntu/)
- [The Beginners Guide To Cron Jobs](https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/)

Using '@reboot' you can Run a command once, at startup.

**Wrapping up**:
`$ sudo crontab -e -u root`

And add a line at the end of the file with your command as follows:

```
@reboot sudo searchd
```