# Running a php process on startup in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, stream, startup

I'm in a school project and we use a process of collecting tweets through a stream set up with PHP. I usually run it in background through the terminal with a command like:
nohup ./mystream.php 2>&1 &

This stream is supposed to be on at all times and thus I would like to make sure that this process starts up whenever the system reboots. How would I do that in Ubuntu?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683357/ubuntu-run-command-on-start-up-with-sudo

Answer (score 3):

You would make it part of a script that runs doing startup. We have done this with things like [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) which replaces the `sbin/init/` daemon. Here is an example script -

```
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=eth0
respawn

exec /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/your/process.php
```