# Starting Nitrogen Web framework at boot time

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, yaws, nitrogen, erlangweb

I have always started nitrogen to run as a daemon using the command below:

```
sudo /home/someuser/myapp/bin/nitrogen start
```

It works well but i have to repeat the same activity should the server reboot.

Most web servers by default start at boot time. When nitrogen is started, it starts the underlying Erlang web server. Unfortunately I have not found any single resource talking about starting nitrogen at boot time.

How do you start nitrogen as a daemon at system boot time?

Comment: You might need an OS service for that. Looks like you are using Linux. What distribution and version do you have?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Comment: There is a good answer from chops, also check out these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683357/ubuntu-run-command-on-start-up-with-sudo , https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to use the `/etc/rc.local` file. By default, it's empty.

Since rc.local runs as root, you can use it as such (though if you prefer to run Nitrogen as a separate user, using `su -c "command" username`) is good.

Anyway, the simple solution is to add to your rc.local file the following:

To run as root:

```
/home/someuser/myapp/bin/nitrogen start
```

To run as another user:

```
su -c "/home/someuser/myapp/bin/nitrogen start" someuser
```

That will launch Nitrogen appropriately and will let you connect to the VM using `bin/nitrogen attach`.

My previous recommendation of using `sudo` is not sufficient, as it doesn't reset the environment to the user you want.

I'm using this in production on Ubuntu 14.04 and a linode VPS.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I am afraid your solution looks straight forward but I do not know whats I am doing wrong. I have tried both options and they have failed to work. Do i have to carry out any other changes to the rc.local file to work?

Comment: I'm curious what part isn't working: Does the Erlang VM Start up at all? Or does it start up, but is not responding to connections? Can you attach to the VM with `bin/nitrogen attach`? If you do a `ps aux | grep nitrogen` does anything come up?

Comment: I realize that in my original answer, I completely forgot to mention the location of rc.local must be `/etc/rc.local`, just in case that was not clear

Comment: Any luck since last posting?

Comment: Well the sudo -u option worked on my laptop but after preceeding the statement with 'sleep 15'. I tried it on the virtual server and it did not work.

Comment: Interesting. It works just fine on my local VM. Is this running on a local VM, or something more like a Linode/Digital Ocean/Cloud-whatever VM? Are you able to attach to the running VM, or does it show in `ps aux`?

Comment: I am running it on Linode VM. On my local VM it runs after preceding with `sleep 15` but i failed to attach to it successfully. Yes it does show in `ps aux | grep nitrogen`

Comment: Verrrry interesting. I'll play with Linode and see what I can come up with.

Comment: I've been doing some further research on this, and I think I'll have a script ready for you to try soon.

Comment: Looking up to you for a lasting solution.

Comment: Alrighty, here's the dumb solution I came up with that works for me on 14.04 and a linode. Add to your rc.local file: `su -c "/path/to/nitrogen_app/bin/nitrogen start" desired_username`  I'm updating my answer in a moment.

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand why it does not work!

Comment: Weird. I'm not sure. It's working for me.  I made one change to the `bin/nitrogen` script (https://github.com/nitrogen/nitrogen/commit/fd48133ed91cec9d0b9e751fcea9172b0a00d984), but that change was because I have many applications running on a single machine, each under a different username from their respective `home` directory.

Comment: What you could try is to scatter some `logger` messages throughout the `nitrogen` script (like this: https://github.com/nitrogen/nitrogen/blob/master/rel/overlay/common/bin/nitrogen#L291) to see what's happening. You can then see the results in the syslog (`/var/log/syslog`).

Comment: This approach at times but no always starts nitrogen but what I realized it does not load some of the application dependence modules making the application unable to work at boot time. I am afraid at times it does not start at all! So I depend on backup servers in case the main servers go off without warning.

Comment: It doesn't always load the dependency Erlang applications, or do you mean other non-Erlang applications that your app depends on (like, say a database server)?

Comment: To be specific it does not load the **protocol buffer** _riak-erlang-client_ linking the nitrogen framework to the Riak database. The client is included in the framework through the file **rebar.conf**.

Comment: I realized the reason why the application fails to work after nitrogen starting at boot time is because Mnesia database which is part of the application fails to normally. With **FATAL** mnesia_tm crashed - cannot read the schema report

Comment: Interesting. That definitely gives you a bit of insight into what's going on. I've not used mnesia enough to know how to fix that problem, but that certainly sounds like it's giving you some decent hints enough so to fix it.