# Automatically Start Multiple MySQL instances on boot in Ubuntu Trusty 14.04

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm still learning how to use Linux & MySQL, so please keep answers simple :)

I've been following this tutorial : 
http://www.ducea.com/2009/01/19/running-multiple-instances-of-mysql-on-the-same-machine/

Both MySQL instances (the default instance you get on installing MySQL and the new one I created in the aforementioned tutorial) are working correctly.

But, when I boot up my OS, only the first (default instance) starts up, so I have to manually start the second instance.

I've been doing this by running these commands as root:

Start the instance:

```
mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/mysql2/my.cnf &
```

Connect:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307
```

How do I make it so that both of these instances will start at boot time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by simply running the command at startup by using the solution in this question :

[Ubuntu - Run command on start-up with "sudo"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683357/ubuntu-run-command-on-start-up-with-sudo)

**Steps I took :** 
 
I added this command to the "/etc/rc.local" file as root:
(Before the "exit 0:" line or it will never get executed)

```
sudo mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/mysql2/my.cnf &
```

Then I restarted my OS. The new instance is now automatically started :), so now I have both starting on boot!

Though now i wonder.. is this the correct way to handle this issue?