# How to configure ports on apache server for iperf3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, iperf

I'm using my apache server for running TCP and UDP traffic using **iperf3**.
I manually execute a command on my server to listen to a port.

```
~# iperf3 -i 5 -s -p 7759
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 7759
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to configure my apache server to have few ports (say 7760,7761,7762,...7770) **permanently  open**  on my apache server for iperf traffic so  that I  don't have to manually execute the aforementioned command to open the port for iperf traffic

Comment: Are you asking how to run iperf as a daemon on an ubuntu linux machine?

Comment: @ Dmitri Chubarov . My question how to configure webserver to have few ports open for iperf3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the definition of *permanently open*.

If ports **remaining open after you log out from your webserver** is sufficiently good approximation of permanently open. Then all you need is start `iperf` with `nohup` command.

```
     nohup iperf3 -s -p 7759 >/tmp/log 2>&1
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/285015/1328439) for more details on keeping backround processes after the shell that spawned them terminates. In particular, check out the answers that suggest using the `screen` command.

If you need iperf server to **keep the ports open between reboots** you need to configure the `init` process to spawn `iperf3` at boot up time. For this you need root access to your webserver.

As root you could add the following lines to `/etc/rc.local` file

```
iperf3 -s -p 7759 > /tmp/iperf-7759.log 2>&1 &
iperf3 -s -p 7760 > /tmp/iperf-7760.log 2>&1 &
... 
iperf3 -s -p 7760 > /tmp/iperf-7770.log 2>&1 &
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9683357/1328439) on how to ensure a command is run every time the machine starts.